# not responding while login

Tags: function, codeigniter, authentication, controller

I am new to CodeIgniter, and am trying to write code to log in after registering using a username and password in registration form using a PHPMyAdmin database. I am not getting anything when I try to log in, and it doesn't display an error or any message.

```
public function login() {   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'Password');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

        //check user in database
        $this->db->select('username' , 'password');
        $this->db->from('user_register');
        $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $user = $query->row();

        if($user->email){

            $this->session->set_flashdata("Successful login");

            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;

        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata("Error No such record found");

        }
    }

    // load view and showing login form
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Comment: When you say 'using a PHPMyAdmin database' do you mean you entered a username and password directly into the user record in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: yes , while using registration form i have added the username and password for that.

Comment: so i am just taking out the username and password from registration 
 table in database...and using that both field i am trying to login..

Comment: Is CodeIngniter hashing your password when you save it?

Comment: no it didn't hash the password,,only showing original password

Comment: You should use some thing like http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to hash password and then to verify use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: i am confused with the url in codeigniter...Please help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Suggestion by [webmasterdro's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514749/5077564) Answer.

I would like to extend it a little bit.

Looking at your code it looks like you have added the query to the controller. 
And as a suggestion, if you are using an MVC framework then try to follow some basic MVC flow. because if you are not following that then it will be useless to use a framework.

- User Controller to handle the post data and validations.
- Use model to do the database query.
- Use `__construct` for loading the common model or libraries.
- Do not save plane password use md5 or other encryption technique.
- Store User detail to the session which you can use further in after login.
- Codeigniter has a great user guide. Try to follow that.

So, your code Should be your like this below.

#### Controller:

```
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

// Load model
$this->load->model('login_database');

}

public function your_controller_function_name() { 

    // Check validation for user input in SignUp form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login_form_view');
    } else {

        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");

        $result = $this->login_database->registration_insert($username, $password);
        //You can do this also if($result != FALSE) 
        if (!empty($result)) {

        // You can set other data to the session also form here 
        $session_data = array(
        'username' => $result['user_name']          
        );

        // Add user data in session
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

        // You can set flash data here

        $this->load->view('your_view'); 

    }  else {

        $data = array(
        'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
        );      
        $this->load->view('your_login_form_view', $data);
    }   

}

}
```

#### Model:

```
// Read data using username and password
public function login($username, $password) {

        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->from('user_register');
        $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $user_data = $query->row_array();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return user_data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

I have not added detail related to flash data because the previous answer has explained it properly.

Comment: please help me out of the url's..i am getting confused how to call and which method need to call in controller..like i create two function login and forget...how to call in url to show these two function..

Comment: Sure, but first update your question with this new controller function `forget` @FerozKhan

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the documentation, looks like you skip that part, but it's very important!

Let's code a little bit and fix the bugs!

**User data**

Well, users will enter their data and we will check, if evertyhing is correct, we can redirect user to the protected page. You call for variables (see Query:) but you I'm not seeing on your code. You should put like that, before your query job

```
$username = $this->input->post("username");
$password = $this->input->post("password");
```

Now, you will be able to use the `where` to get the user data. =)

**Query:**

If read about OOP with PHP, you know that when you pass parameters to a method, each parameter have their own "action". In case of the `select` method, you should keep the data you want to select, on the same quote, because you the way you do, it's like you passing multiple parameters to the method.

```
 $this->db->select('username, password'); 
 $this->db->from('user_register');
 $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

First, to decide if the record exist or not, I prefer this way:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $user_data = $query->row();

      // We should verify if the user entered the password that correspond to the account. 
      // If not, we tell them that the password is incorrect.
      if($password != $user_data->password) {
           $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Wrong password!");
           return redirect(site_url());
       }

       // You can use the CI built in methods to work with sessions
       $this->session->set_userdata(array(
              'username' => $user_data->username,
       ));

       $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "You are logged in!");
       return redirect(site_url());

} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("Error: No such record found");
    redirect(site_url());
}
```

**Flash data**

Yeah, we use flashdata to show a message for the user. But, you should pass an `item` and the `value` of this item. Like that:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfully logged in!");
```

And, to retrieve the data on your views, you can do like...

```
<?php 

$success = $this->session->flashdata("success");
$error = $this->session->flashdata("error");

if(!empty($success)) {
      echo $success;
}

if(!empty($success)) {
      echo $error;
}

?>
```

**Recommendations**

- Sessions: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html
- Database: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Also, I recommed you, to take a minute on YouTube, to understand CodeIgniter.

If I forgot something, let me know! =)

Comment: nice suggestion. @Webmasterdro